# Getting the monthly aggregate precipitation values from ERA5-Land Monthly Averaged - ECMWF Climate Reanalysis

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, precipitation

I have a problem with the ERA 5 - Dataset. What I need are the monthly aggregated values for the precipitation in my region.
In the  "ERA5 Monthly Aggregates - Latest Climate Reanalysis Produced by ECMWF" I would get the right datas, but sadly they just go to mid 2020, but I need from 2018 - 2021.
So I am using "ERA5-Land Monthly Averaged - ECMWF Climate Reanalysis" instead. But when I use the reducer median here, I just get the median for the daily precipitation. For the chart I found a solution in the reducer.sum, but for the map I need a solution. So I need a map with the median of the aggregated Precipitation values.
I hope, you understand and can help.

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2Flaraemsinghoff%2FStart%3AKlima

```
Map.centerObject(table);

var starting = '2018-01-01';
var ending = '2018-12-01';

var Precipitation = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('total_precipitation').clip(geometry);
  return bands.rename('Precipitaion')
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var eraPrec = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY")
.filterDate(starting , ending)
.filterBounds(geometry)
.map(Precipitation);

print(eraPrec);
  

print(
  ui.Chart.image.series(eraPrec, table, ee.Reducer.sum(), 3000, 'system:time_start')
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Precipitaion (ERA-5 Monthly)' + ' ' + starting,
    vAxis: {title: 'm'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    series: {0: {color: 'blue'}}
  })
);

//ERA map
     var ERA = eraPrec.select(['Precipitaion']);
     var ERAsum = ERA.sum();
    var pal = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']


 Map.addLayer (
       ERAmed.clip (geometry),
       {min: 0 , max: 0.1, palette: pal },
       'Niederschlag'
       );
       
 



//export ERA
 
 var export_map = ERAsum.clip(geometry).select (['Precipitaion']);
 
 Export.image.toDrive ({image: export_map, description: 'ERA_Westfalen2018', scale: 3000});
```